# one dimensional differential equation coordinate transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to show that there exist a coordinate transformation $x\longmapsto y=x+\delta x^2$, with $\delta$ constant, such that the following ODE  $$\dfrac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ix^i} \tag{given that $a_1\not=0$}$$ transforms into $$\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=a_1y+ey^3+... $$ with $e$ as some constant. Furthermore I need to show with induction that for every n there exist a coordinate transformation such that $\dfrac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}$ transforms into:

$$\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=a_1z+\mathcal{O}(z^n)$$

> I have tried the following: 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}&=\dfrac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}+\delta (2x) \dfrac{\text{d}(x^2)}{\text{d}t}\\
> &=a_1x+\delta(2x)(a_1x+a_2x^2)
> \end{align}$$

But I don't think that this is going to work. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Just a suggestion: Don't use $e$ as a constant when it is not equal to $2.71828\ldots$.  Also, don't use the $\delta$ as a constant in differential equations, as it can be somewhat confused with the Dirac Delta function, depending on how you write it.  (e.g. $\delta(2x)$ looks like you are plugging in $2x$ into the Dirac Delta function)

Comment: @anorton thank you for your suggestion. I will be more careful the next time. But can you give me hints about how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see what you problem is, apart from a mistake in the second line of the shaded equation: you only report $a_1 x$ for $dx/dt$, inexplicably - & incorrectly & inconveniently - omitting all the rest. (You do the same for $dx^2/dt$, but it's less inconvenient there.) So, do report that term, combine $x^2-$terms together, & demand that their coefficient vanishes - this will yield $\delta$. Note, also, that $a_1$ **will** change! The coefficient of the linear term in the ODE for $y$ is corrected by a $\delta-$amount. Can you take it form here?